# How to make facade for several pipes in Gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following task in my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('theme.scss')
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

and I want to move all those pipes to one module in order to get something like that:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('theme.scss')
    .pipe(theme())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you might be able to create a separate function, like wrapped(), which returns this.pipe(..).pipe(..)  , then bind your context to it when invoked.  like `pipe(wrapped().bind(this))` , or something similar.  On my phone right now, but I can try to play around with this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with [lazypipe](https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe) and my separate module has been implemented in this way:

```
module.exports = function () {
  var pipes = lazypipe()
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(...);

  return pipes();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would imagine would be something like this:

```
function theme(stream) {
    return stream.pipe(less())
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(prefix())
}

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return theme(gulp.src('theme.less'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})
```

(Done with LESS, b/c gulp-ruby-sass now has some new interface).
If you want to be flexible, you can pipe as much as you want in the theme-function:

```
function theme(stream) {
    return stream.pipe(minify())
        .pipe(prefix())
}

gulp.task('less', function() {
    return theme(gulp.src('theme.less').pipe(less()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})
```

It's not as pretty as you might want it to be, but it does the deal without too much extra packages.